# Powershell Script to Display Manager Name by Full Name

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a csv file that tells me users who haven't logged in in 90 days.  It needs to include the Manager for that user but when pulling in the manager from Active Directory, I"m getting the full DN for that manager rather than just the Display Name.  Here's my script...

```
import-module activedirectory
get-aduser -filter * -searchscope subtree -searchbase "ou=user departments ou,dc=acr,dc=org" -properties DisplayName,manager,lastlogontimestamp | 
    ? {(((Get-date) - ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastlogontimestamp))).TotalDays -gt 90)} | 
    select DisplayName,samaccountname,manager,Userprincipalname,@{Exp={([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastlogontimestamp))};label="Last logon time stamp"} | 
    export-csv "c:\scripts\reston_sharepoint_users_120_days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
```

Any suggestions?  The rest of the script works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Use a calculated property for the manager just like you're doing for the `LastLogonTimestamp`.